# Use of ESAPI getValidInput method

Tags: java, esapi

I was not able to use the of method present under `ESAPI` class'

```
    java.lang.String getValidInput(java.lang.String context,
                                  java.lang.String input,
                                  java.lang.String type,
                                  int maxLength,
                                  boolean allowNull)
                                      throws ValidationException,
                                       IntrusionException

      Parameters:
         type - The regular expression name that maps to the actual regular expression from "ESAPI.properties".
```

How to pass parameter type from `ESAPI.properties` file?
Any example to use properties file value from which I can refer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's an example call where I'm validating the "to" address field:

```
validator.getValidInput("toAddress", it.next(), "Email", Email.MAX_ADDRESS_SIZE, true)
```

ESAPI assumes you're using an IDE or have access to the direct source.  If you're using Eclipse, just mouse-hover over the method name, and the parameter types will be displayed.

===UPDATED===

Here's the rip directly from the javadoc:

```
/**
     * Returns canonicalized and validated input as a String. Invalid input will generate a descriptive ValidationException,
     * and input that is clearly an attack will generate a descriptive IntrusionException.
     *
     * @param context
     *      A descriptive name of the parameter that you are validating (e.g., LoginPage_UsernameField). This value is used by any logging or error handling that is done with respect to the value passed in.
     * @param input
     *      The actual user input data to validate.
     * @param type
     *      The regular expression name that maps to the actual regular expression from "ESAPI.properties".
     * @param maxLength
     *      The maximum post-canonicalized String length allowed.
     * @param allowNull
     *      If allowNull is true then an input that is NULL or an empty string will be legal. If allowNull is false then NULL or an empty String will throw a ValidationException.
     *
     * @return The canonicalized user input.
     *
     * @throws ValidationException
     * @throws IntrusionException
     */
```

Comment: `"Email"` feild which you have you here..is it regex defined under ESAPI.properties file?If I am incorrect,please educate..

Comment: In the validation.properties file, you should see a default entry (corresponding to my case up above) like this:  `Validator.Email=^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$1` On the "getValidInput" call, "Email" maps to "Validator.Email"

Comment: Can we add a new regex to esapi.properties file?Because if I tried  to do so I got `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The selected type [DefaultRegex] was not set via the ESAPI validation configuration` where DefaultRegex is regex.

Comment: I'd say we start a new question and you link it here.  The short answer is "yes."

Comment: Actually, you would add those new validation regex patterns to the "validation.properties" file, which should reside in the same directory as the ESAPI.properties file that you are using.

Comment: You certainly can add validation patterns to ESAPI.properties. However, if ESAPI doesn't like your regex, it will quietly drop it, with only a single log statement to that effect, and you'll then get the above "not set via the ESAPI validation configuration" message.

Comment: The problem there isn't ESAPI.  It's an invalid regex syntax.  Could you provide an example input to prove my judgment here wrong?

Comment: If you don't like the log message, we can fix that.

Comment: How to validate Integer Input value

Comment: @srinivasgowda Read the javadoc:  https://static.javadoc.io/org.owasp.esapi/esapi/2.1.0.1/org/owasp/esapi/reference/DefaultValidator.html#getValidInteger(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, int, int, boolean)

Comment: What is import for `Email` for `Email.MAX_ADDRESS_SIZE` ?

Comment: @SabirKhan There is no `Email` class in ESAPI.  Each application is expected to have its own max, therefore it's up to you to create the Email enum.

Answer (score -1):

```
ESAPI.validator().getValidInput("Validationofinput", StringInput, "Onlycharacters",200, true);
```

Comment: Code-only answers aren’t useful for the community. Please look at [answer]