# ESAPI input validation

Tags: validation, esapi

can someone explain me how to do input validation using ESAPI validator.
I have gone through several sites but didnt find the practical code implementation.

Suppose I have a field called as CUSTOMER NAME in string so how can i validate it using ESAPI validators in java+jsp

Thanks

Comment: Possible Duplicate:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22664006/use-of-esapi-getvalidinput-method/22669479#22669479

Comment: And BTW... I would recommend against doing operations within the JSP.  JSP compilation is 10000x slower on average than validations done correctly on your web controller.

Comment: Go through the below..It might help you.https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet